# Ошибка при выполнении команды apt update && apt upgrade

Tags: linux, администрирование, update, kali-linux

[image]

Версия Kali Linux 2019.1
Я не понимаю, что не так.

Comment: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?36436-connection-refused-during-update

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим:

```
$ ping repo.kali.org
PING urania.kali.org (51.161.119.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns571933.ip-51-161-119.net (51.161.119.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=176 ms
```

Т.е. хост по URL repo.kali.org существует и он живой. Пошли дальше:

```
$ nmap -p 443  repo.kali.org
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-07-01 11:57 +07
Nmap scan report for repo.kali.org (51.161.119.11)
Host is up (0.17s latency).
rDNS record for 51.161.119.11: ns571933.ip-51-161-119.net

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.44 seconds
```

Но порт 443 закрыт! Почему - это вопрос к администрации сервера. Если в конфиге *apt* имеется несколько репозитариев - просто закомментируйте эту строку и попробуйте с оставшимися.

Если в конфиге больше нет ничего подходящего, ищите и пробуйте другие хранители репозитариев. Как это сделать - почитайте вот тут:

https://itsecforu.ru/2020/01/28/%F0%9F%90%A7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE/